# Is It Possible to Get SFT from FFT?

Tags: iphone, core-audio

I use Auriotouch sample program to generate FFT data to get Frequency and magnitude. Is there any easy method available to get SFT from FFT?

Comment: What do you mean by the abbreviation SFT?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If by SFT you mean DFT (the Discrete Fourier Transform of a finite vector or array of equally spaced audio sample values), it is identical to the result of an FFT computation (plus or minus some tiny numerical rounding differences) of that same sample vector.

Comment: Yes. I think DFT is what I need. Is it possible to generate DFT out of FFT.

Comment: They are essentially the same.  What exactly are you looking for?

Comment: I am looking for comparable data (frequency and magnitude) pertaining two sound files to compare two sound samples.